# Laravel Controller Validation Date

Tags: php, validation, laravel

My controller design for my form is to validate the dateline of project and the dateline start date of the project.

Would like to start of with the validation. As the logic goes. Dateline cant be before start date. if possible to return a custom error message.

```
public function create(){
        $this -> validate($request, [
            'projectName' => 'required|max:255',
            'projectDescrip' => 'required',
        ]);

        if(startDate > Dateline){

        }

        $project = new Project();
        $project -> project_id = $projects -> id;
        $project -> projectName = $projects -> ProjectName;
        $project -> dateline = $projects -> dateline;
        $project -> startDate = $projects -> startDate;
        $project -> user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    }
```

Comment: What's your question? I hope you don't want us to complete your code for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to validate, but if you're using a form then the best approach is to use [Form Request Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#form-request-validation). It makes for cleaner code. But to demonstrate the date validation, in the controller you can:

```
$rules = [
    'dateline_start' => 'required|date',
    'dateline_finish' => 'required|date|after:dateline_start',
    //Additional rules go here
];

//Custom error messages
$messages = [
    'dateline_finish.after' => 'Dateline cant be before start date',
    //Additional custom error messages
];


$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect('where/they/should/go')
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();
}
```

That's one way at it.